# Invalid operands to binary expression [xcode c++]

Tags: c++, string, if-statement, c++11, char

Why do I have this error in my code?

```
void check_letter(string letter, string entry) {
    for(int i = 0; i < entry.length(); i++) {
        if(entry[i] == letter) {

        }
    }
}
```

> Invalid operands to binary expression ('std::basic_string<char>::value_type' (aka 'char') and 'std::string' (aka 'basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char>>'))`

I want to check each letter in the word, so I check all letters of the word in a loop. I tried it on a array char (I made the array with individual letters from the word) and I had the same error.

Comment: Assuming that, as its name suggests, `letter` is always a single letter then `if (entry[i] == letter[0])` will work. Basic fact about C++ is that strings and characters are different types.

Answer (score 4):

`entry[i]` is a `char`, `letter` is a `std::string` - and there is no `bool operator==(const char&, const std::string&)` so you can't compare the two for equality.

You could change the function to `void check_letter(char letter, const string& entry)` to make it search for an individual `char` in `entry`.

Note: [`std::string::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) can search for an individual `char` (overload 4) and returns the index of the found `char` (or `std::string::npos` if not found).

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to compare a single character with a whole string:

```
if(entry[i] == letter)
```

Instead you could write for example:

```
if ( letter.find( entry[i] ) != std::string::npos ) {
   //...
```

> I tried it on a array char (I made the array with individual letters
> from the word) and I had the same error

You may not also to compare a whole array with a character.
If for example the variable `letter` is declared as a character array then you could use standard C string function `strchr` declared in header `<cstring>` to determine whether a character is present in the array.

For example:

```
#include <cstring>

//...

if ( strchr( letter, entry[i] ) != nullptr ) {
    //...
```

Also it is not a good idea to declare the function like:

```
void check_letter(string letter, string entry);
```

You should declare parameters as having referenced types as for example:

```
void check_letter(string &letter, string *entry);
```

Or you could add qualifier `const` if strings are not changed in the function like:

```
void check_letter( const string &letter, const string *entry);
```

Maybe it would be even better to use `std::string_view` instead of `std::string` as the function parameter type.